# ios app not visible in photos

Tags: ios, photo, privacy, photo-gallery

The app that I am developing needs access to the photo gallery. I have added the following code to check whether I have access to it.

```
 ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
    if (status != ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        NSString *alertMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"PHOTOS_AUTHORIZATION_ALERT_MESSAGE", nil);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"PHOTOS_AUTHORIZATION_ALERT_TITLE", nil)
                                        message:alertMessage
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        });
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
```

But sometimes iPhone 5s running iOS 8.4 and always iPhone 6 Plus running iOS 9 does not show my app under the privacy photos list.

Comment: Could it be because it's deprecated, and you should use Photo.framework?